# Write Excel Cell Comment using Python on Linux?

Tags: python

I am using `Python` in a Linux (Ubuntu) environment.

How do I go about writing a  **comment** into a cell in an `Excel` file (say,`MyFile.xls`)?

I know that it is possible to write **values**. Yet, how do I go about writing a comment?

Comment: Does it have to be .xls or can you use .xlsx?

Comment: `.xls` is much preferred (as I don't have `Office 2007`).

Comment: Too bad. `.xlsx` is just XML files in a zip archive, and Python knows how to deal with both of those. `.xls` is much harder.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: thank you. Suppose I can deal with `.xlsx` -- how should I go about it?

Comment: Unfortunately while I know it can be done, I don't know exactly how to go about it or I'd write up an answer. The easiest part is figuring out which part of the XML must be modified: create two documents, one with the comment and one without, and compare them to see which element was added.

Comment: Comments!? What is a comment? The values can be just text, they won't do anything, how would a comment be different?

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: I don't understand your response. Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: No. Can you explain what the difference between a comment and a text string is in a spreadsheet?

Comment: Every cell has its contents; yet, in addition to the actual contents, every cell can contain a `comment`. my question was, how do I get (from within `python`) to write a `comment` for some cell?

Comment: @user3262424 - are you using any particular python library to read your excel files?

Comment: John Machin occasionally visits SO, and he can probably confirm one way or the other; but as far as I'm aware, xlrd/xlwt don't handle cell comments. Comments aren't simple to handle, as they can contain rich, formatted text; and the structures within the .xls file changed quite dramatically between BIFF5 and BIFF8... adding to the complexities of handling them.

Comment: @Mark: `xlrd` can be modified to support reading comments. I don't know about `xlwt` -- it's a good question to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows (with Excel installed) you could use COM from Python: [this class wraps it nicely for you](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/528870-class-for-writing-content-to-excel-and-formatting-/).

But on Linux, you'll need to use [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt).

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into this myself and found https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/wiki/Home .
It is a new library that allows editing xlsx files.
I'm not sure if it allows editing comments though.